# Check for empty cell in a particular column of a QTableWiget and remove the row

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I have 2 columns in my QTableWidget, the first column is populated with text while the second is populated with combobox.

In my table, there are a few rows in which they are not populated with comboboxes as they failed to fulfill one of the checks that I made, and so, in their second column, no combobox are created and they appear as empty cell.

How can I check for such empty cells in the second column and remove the entire rows?

I tried the following while searching online for a solution:

```
for row in xrange(self.my_table.rowCount()):
    column_cell = self.my_table.item(row, 1)
    column_text = str(column_cell.text())
    if column_text.isEmpty():
        self.my_table.removeRow(row_position)
```

And I got the following error:
`# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' #`
I suppose this is because my cell are not line edit etc and so no text?

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make more sense to check whether the cell contains a widget, rather than whether it contains any text. Also, you must iterate in *reverse* so that removing rows does not affect the indexes of the remaining rows:

```
for row in reversed(xrange(self.my_table.rowCount())):
    widget = self.my_table.cellWidget(row, 1)
    if widget is None:
        self.my_table.removeRow(row)
```